# How to click on button within a div SELENIUM Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have to click on the button `Accepter et continuer` in this `div`,
I copied the XPATH of the line on which is present the button I want to click, but it does not work

```
<div class="disclaimer-buttons-place-holder">
    <a class="btn btn-reverse" href="WEBSITE" data-event-zone="click" data-event="C" data-event-label="action::disclaimer::exit" data-event-type="A"> Refuser</a>
    <a class="btn" id="validateDisclaimer" href="/fr_part" data-event-zone="click" data-event="C" data-event-label="action::disclaimer::validate" data-event-type="A"> ccepter et continuer</a>
</div>
```

do you know how to click exactly on the `Accepter et continuer` button using XPATH?

I tried this :

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/aside/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/a[2]").click()
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given the html:

```
<div class="disclaimer-buttons-place-holder">
    <a class="btn btn-reverse" href="WEBSITE" data-event-zone="click" data-event="C" data-event-label="action::disclaimer::exit" data-event-type="A"> Refuser</a>
    <a class="btn" id="validateDisclaimer" href="/fr_part" data-event-zone="click" data-event="C" data-event-label="action::disclaimer::validate" data-event-type="A"> ccepter et continuer</a>
</div>
```

The desired element is a dynamic element.

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "ccepter et continuer"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn#validateDisclaimer[data-event-label$='validate']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn' and @id='validateDisclaimer'][contains(@data-event-label, 'validate') and contains(., 'ccepter et continuer')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answering, unfortunately I don't think the solution works.. I tried all of them, but it fails.

Comment: @jacoposalmistrari Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: ok ! I posted the comment there